# Activate/Deactivate field by bottom(HTML+Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I like to activate 2 field in row by clicking on activate1 while other fields not change and by activator2 the other two field and so on, need to these three activator bottom just to activate 2 field separately, I'm completely new in JavaScript and HTML that's why this might seem so simple
I had used the code in the following link. however when I hit the Activator1 all field activated and deactivated.

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="1">
  <label class="btn btn-default"> Activar1   
  </label>
</div> 
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="prueba"/>
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="prueba"/>

<div>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="2">
  <label class="btn btn-default"> Activar2   
  </label>
</div> 
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="prueba"/>
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="prueba"/>
</div>
<div>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="3">
  <label class="btn btn-default"> Activar3   
  </label>
</div> 
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="prueba"/>
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="prueba"/>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$( 'body' ).on( 'click', '#1', function(event) {    
    if( $(this).attr('data-toggle') != 'button' ) { $(this).toggleClass('active');      }
    if( $(this).hasClass( 'active' ) == true )    { $("input").prop('disabled', false); }
    if( $(this).hasClass( 'active' ) == false )   { $("input").prop('disabled', true);  }
});

$( 'body' ).on( 'click', '#2', function(event) {    
    if( $(this).attr('data-toggle') != 'button' ) { $(this).toggleClass('active');      }
    if( $(this).hasClass( 'active' ) == true )    { $("input").prop('disabled', false); }
    if( $(this).hasClass( 'active' ) == false )   { $("input").prop('disabled', true);  }
});
$( 'body' ).on( 'click', '#3', function(event) {    
    if( $(this).attr('data-toggle') != 'button' ) { $(this).toggleClass('active');      }
    if( $(this).hasClass( 'active' ) == true )    { $("input").prop('disabled', false); }
    if( $(this).hasClass( 'active' ) == false )   { $("input").prop('disabled', true);  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r37ocau0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this helps. Your issue is that when you select `$("input").prop("disabled` you are selecting every input element. I re-wrote your js so that you only have to write the action out once, and I made the target input elements relative to the label clicked. Good luck!

```js
$(".btn-group label").click(function (event) {
  const divContainer = event.target.parentElement;
  const targetContainer = divContainer.parentElement;
  const relatedInput = targetContainer.querySelectorAll("input");
  relatedInput.forEach(ele => {
  
    if( $(ele).attr('data-toggle') != 'button' )
      $(ele).toggleClass('active');
      
    if( $(ele).hasClass( 'active' ) == true )   
      $(ele).prop('disabled', false);
      
    if( $(ele).hasClass( 'active' ) == false )   
      $(ele).prop('disabled', true);
      
  });
});
```

```css
.btn-group label {
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="1">
    <label class="btn btn-default"> Activar1   
    </label>
  </div> 
  <input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="prueba"/>
  <input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="prueba"/>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="2">
    <label class="btn btn-default"> Activar2   
    </label>
  </div> 
  <input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="prueba"/>
  <input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="prueba"/>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="3">
    <label class="btn btn-default"> Activar3   
    </label>
  </div> 
  <input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="prueba"/>
  <input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="prueba"/>
</div>
```